# AngularJS - multiple API calls with cached responses

Tags: angularjs, promise

I want my controller to be able to fetch a list of indicators from an API via a service:

Controller.js

```
dataService.getIndicators( ["a", "b", "c"] )
```

DataService.js

```
this.cachedIndicators = {};
var baseURL = "www.myapi.com/jsonp/indicator/";
this.getIndicators = function(indicators){
    //for each indicator not in cache, retrieve it using $http.jsonp()
    //when done, indicate that data 
}
```

Can I make use of AngularJS caching and promises here? (a sample implementation would be much welcome.)

Comment: Can't you enabled [the cache of the `$http` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#caching)?

Answer (score 1):

In case every indicator has its own resource and you need to make multiple requests and want to wait until all requests are done you use the $q.all(..) method which returns a single promise wrapping multiple promises.

for example:

```
this.getIndicators = $q.all([
    $http.jsonp(url1, { cache: true }).then( .. process individual result here ..),
    $http.jsonp(url2, { cache: true })
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. In your service, return the promise which is the result of the $http.jsonp() call...

```
this.cachedIndicators = {};
var baseURL = "www.myapi.com/jsonp/indicator/";
this.getIndicators = function(indicators){
    return $http.jsonp(baseURL, { cache: true });
}
```

...then modify your controller to handle the result of the promise...

```
dataService.getIndicators( ["a", "b", "c"] ).then(function(data){
    // do stuff with the returned data
});
```